# Is it possible to have Segmentation Fault using numpy eigenvectors calculation in numpy version 1.7.1

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-computing, slurm

I'm using a cluster which has a very old  version of Numpy (1.7.1). I'm using python 3.8.5 (but in 2.7 the problem is the same). I have a code which involves calculating the eigenvector of a large hermitian matrix and the do some calculations with those vectors.

In my computer, with numpy 1.21.0 I can go basically any size that my RAM can but in The cluster it work until N (being the  linear size of the matrix. [the total is N^2]) equals 2*35^2 but beyond it gives segmentantion fault (core dumped).

I Know that this is a thing in C/C++ but in Python I don't know how to solve it.

Since the only difference between my PC and the Server is the numpy version that's it the problem or maybe I have a undercover bug in the code?

I give the GitHub Link for the code: https://github.com/nic677/Chern_Number/blob/main/Chern_Wfixo_Bvariable.py

**atention**: The function *Hamil* it's just creating the matrix, the code itself it's under it.

**Aditional Info**: I Submit the program to cluster by slurm

Comment: I'm guessing it's a memory error at a low enough level that it quits rather than raise a proper error message.

Comment: Yes, as it is a segmentation fault I suppose it's in numpy implementation of C (or Fortran tho).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I Found the problem. I replicate the system in another (Windows) PC with the same numpy and Python version. Python 3.3 (the most up to data version that supports Numpy 1.7.1) and it Works well!!

However, in the cluster the version used is python 2.7.5 and, when i installed that version the program runs a "Memory Error" in

> rwork = zeros((lwork,), real_t)

For my understanding in C and LAPACK it must be some faulty implementation of it that, eventually, was corrected!